# rChartsDygraphs - data.frame causes error when creating signals

Tags: r, data.table, rcharts

First of all many thanks for the great rChartsDygraphs package! It is working superb and a great extension to the usual plots, but unfortunately I have a problem with signals.

Similar to the example I have a `data.frame` for the signals

```
signals1 <- as.data.frame(signals1)
'data.frame':   2712 obs. of  3 variables:  $ Date : Date, format:
"2004-03-29" "2004-03-30" "2004-03-31" "2004-04-01" ...  $ Price: num 
1.78 1.79 1.78 1.8 1.86 1.9 1.87 1.84 1.85 1.88 ...  $ sig  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
```

However, when applying to the dygraph

```
  d1 <- dygraph(data=as.data.frame(data), 
                sync=TRUE, 
                crosshair="vertical", 
                legendFollow=TRUE, height = 200, width=800,
                title = paste('<font size="1">', Symbol, '</ font>', sep=''),  
                signals = signals1,
                sigFigs=7, 
                axisLabelFontSize = 9)
```

I receive in function sigSeries <- function(colN, signals) in line 4

```
ann <- as.data.table(signals[, c(1, 2, eval(colN)), with = FALSE])
```

following error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(signals, , c(1, 2, eval(colN)), with = FALSE):
unused argument (with = FALSE)
```

I am still getting my head around R and do not understand what is going wrong here as "colN" evaluates fine to int 3 and hence all should work fine?

Just to mention it, without the signals the graph renders absolutely fine... and buys are int 1, sells int -1 while no change are zeros in the sig column.

Did anyone encounter similar issues and could help?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: output from dput(head(signals1))

```
Browse[2]> dput(head(signals1)) structure(list(Date =
structure(c(12506, 12507, 12508, 12509,  12510, 12513), class =
"Date"), Price = c(1.78, 1.79, 1.78, 1.8, 
1.86, 1.9), sig = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Date", "Price",  "sig"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please show the output of `dput(head(signals1))`?

Comment: @Marat Thank you for looking into this and please see the output added to the question.

Comment: Why are you using `with = FALSE` on a data.frame? It is need for data.table.

Comment: @ Arun: the with = FALSE was not in my code but what I found in my debugging attempt in the package I used. The problem seems to be that the documentation requests a data.frame while the function seems to require a data.table.

Comment: The signals feature was my PR to that package, good to see somebody is using it. And sorry for misleading documentation, it was developed on data.tables. I'm not sure if the project will be further developed. There is an active development version of [dygraphs for R](https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs) maintained by rstudio, but I remember it has fewer features.

Comment: @ Jan: Thanks for the feature addition to the project. I actually started with dygraphs for R from rstudio. The missing part was the layout_dygraphs function as i could not get multiple charts in one page. if that would be easily possible I would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `dygraph` requires its `signals` parameter to belong to the `data.table` class, despite the documentation says that it should be just `data.frame`. Thus, to fix the problem you need to load the `data.table` package and replace

```
 signals = signals1,
```

by

```
signals = as.data.table(signals1),
```

in your code.

Comment: @ Marat - Thanks for the answer. It works like charm. I will raise this on the project site as the documentation may mislead some other newbies.